# fetching results from core data in one to many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

All related questions I saw are in Objective C, but I use Swift.
I have a one to many relationship in core data, one "Current" entity to many "Forecast" entities. I manage to save and get the "Current" entity, but fail to do it for the "matching"for my table  "Forecast" entities. The Forecast entities should also be displayed in a UITableView.
This is what I have by now. The array I'm trying to create is always empty. I need some help here:

```
guard let stack = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).stack else {return}
        let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "city_id_forecast", ascending: true)]
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Forecast")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "main==%@", currentFetched!)
        if (currentFetched==nil){
            print("current fetched is nil")
        }
        else{
            print("currentFetched is not nil")
        }
        let fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: stack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "city_id_forecast", cacheName: nil)
        do {try fetchedResultController.performFetch()}
        catch {print ("error in performing fetch results\(error)")}
        let fetched = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects
        //let fetched = fetchedResultController.
        let count = fetched?.count
        print ("count of fetched forecast!: \(count!)")
        for i in 0..<count!{
            let currentFetched = fetched?[i] as? Forecast
            let dateForecast = currentFetched?.value(forKeyPath: "date_forecast") as! String
            let tempForecast = currentFetched?.value(forKeyPath: "temperature_forecast") as! String
            let iconForecast = currentFetched?.value(forKeyPath: "icon_forecast") as! String
            let forecastElement = "\(dateForecast), \(tempForecast), \(iconForecast)"

            forecastArray.append(forecastElement)
```

Comment: There should be no need to explicitly fetch the forecast entities; You can just get the list from the reference attribute on the current entity.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @Paulw11

Comment: Your `Current` object will have a reference property, say `forecasts` which is the to-many relationship; this property is a collection of `Forecast` entities.  Once you have a `Current` entity you get the referenced `Forecast` entities by simply accessing this collection; there is no need to explicitly query for them; put them in an array and use that to drive a table view.

Comment: Does it mean that fetchedResultController.performFetch() is needless? In the line:  let fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: stack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "city_id_forecast", cacheName: nil), should I expect fetchedResultController  have all the forecast records? It doesn't. @Paulw11

Comment: You don't need a fetched results controller at all; your relationship property on your `Current` object already has all of the `Forecast` NSManagedObjects